# Python-MySQLdb module for Python 2.7.2 and MySQL 5.6.10

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I have Python 2.7.2 running in mac os x 10.8.3 and MySQL 5.6.10, is there an easy way of installing the mysqldb module for python?

I tried Macports py27-mysqldb but it installed everything: python, mysql and mysqldb module, I only want to install the module.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is using pip :

```
pip install mysql-python
```

Answer (score 0):

try `easy_install`, i.e.

```
$ sudo easy_install MySQL-python
```