# how to install mysql on python 2.7.5 and mysql 5.6

Tags: python, mysql, centos

I have `centos` `Mysql5.6` and `python 2.7.5`.
I am trying this

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.4

But it only supports mysql5.5 not 5.6

How can i find the latest version which supports `mysql5.6`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the [current](http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-Python/mysql-connector-python-1.0.11-1.el6.noarch.rpm/from/http://cdn.mysql.com/) python "drivers" from the [mysql site](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/1.0.html). Since centos is Red Hat based that's the drop down item you'll want to select. I would think that the drivers you get from that site would be compatible with version 5.6, although I don't know for sure.

Also from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15848691/python-mysqldb-module-for-python-2-7-2-and-mysql-5-6-10) you should be able to use pip

```
pip install mysql-python
```